# Star schema imperative for using Mondrian?

Tags: data-warehouse, olap-cube, mondrian, degenerate-dimension

I am seeing different implied answers to this question. Can a single 'flat' fact table be used simply referencing the different columns from the Mondrian schema?

Comment: Could you concretize you question? Could you provide a simple example? That would help to understand it better.

Answer (score 0):

That will be a special case where you only have [degenerate dimensions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_dimension). I do not see why it shouldn't be supported.

It is a design decision with different implications but certainly seems viable.